# Polygon does not draw correctly in Open Street Map

Tags: android, ios, openstreetmap, mapbox, skmaps

I used Skobbler Android SDK to draw Polygon and Polyline, but this happened on MapBox and iOS as well, so I think it may be a general issue in Open Street Map..

When I add Polygon and Polyline with exactly same Coordinate list, I have different result below.

[image]

Polyline draws correctly for coordinates, but Polygon draws strangely. Why does Polygon do this kind of wrong behaviour and how to draw same as Polyline correctly??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its not "a general issue in Open Street Map". Its an issue with the Skobbler SDK, if at all :)

Comment: I am not sure, however I tried it on MapBox and Skobbler, and had exactly same issue, that's why I am thinking that way. Anyway, if you have any thought about the issue??

Comment: @scal, Are you sure it is an issue with the Skobbler SDK?? If then, why??

Comment: Because this polygon has nothing to do with OpenStreetMap. OpenStreetMap is a database of free geographic data and you are using OSM just for the map background. The polygon doesn't exist in the OSM database and is therefore an issue of your SDK. Unfortunately that doesn't solve the problem for you :)

Comment: Thanks scai. I understand your point... If then, do you know why it happens and how to fix the issue on Skobbler and MapBox??

Comment: Sorry, I've never worked with these frameworks.

Comment: @mooongcle this is a bug that will be fixed in a next release. Sorry, we don't have any workarounds for the meantime.